# Replace Class inside Table TD after Clone and before Append using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jquery to clone the row from SOURCE table & append it in TARGET table.
After clone & before APPEND I want to remove class "my_green" & also replace class "search_row" with another class "final_row".

```
<tr>
    <td class='text-center' id='111'>
    <span class='my_green search_row'  aria-hidden='true' >
    </td>
    <td>KoaMsRohEdDfg2C</td>
    <td class='text-nowrap' >C-12-5-16</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Silver</td>
</tr>


$('document').ready(function(){

 $('.source_table').on('click', function (e) {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();

    $(row).addClass("remove");
    // Here I want to remove "my_green" class from clone 
   // and also replace "search_row" class with another class "final_row".

    $('.target_table').append(row);

});

$(document).on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just find your class identifier, remove your class and toggle between your 2 class. Please try:

```
row.addClass("remove").find(".search_row").removeClass("my_green").toggleClass("final_row search_row");
```